# HTML/Javascript - Create a section of the page that autoscrolls, and removes the top text as it goes off the screen

Tags: javascript, html, css, scroll

I'm creating a minimalist web page that involves processing tweets in realtime on the backend. Some of the tweets will be passed to the frontend through a socket to be displayed. I want the entire left side of the screen to be devoted to displaying tweets(I already divided up the page using a div). They should be appended, and it should scroll as they are. However, here's the important part: I don't want a scroll bar at any point in time. When the entire left side fills up, I want the tweets at the top to be removed as tweets at the bottom are added. The goal is to give the illusion of the tweets running off the screen, but are removed to save memory once they're completely off the screen.

I have no idea how to implement this. At the moment, I'm just adding to a textbox like so:

```
<textarea id='tweets' width='100%' height='100%'></textarea>
```

Javascript:

```
socket.on('newTweet', function(data) {
      tweetBox.innerHTML += data + '\r\n';
    });
```

Another thing I'd like to add is have the background of each tweet alternate in colour. I can implement this myself as long as it's possible(For example, with a textbox, it isn't, unless I'm mistaken)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've made an example which covers your requirements in their most simple form. You'll need to adapt it to your specific needs.

Here's a list of the "techniques" employed to get it all working:

1. Use a `div` which will contain an element for each tweet being displayed instead of a textbox with plain text. This gives you more control over what can be displayed and what you can do with it (i.e.: alternating background colours).
2. Keep track of tweet elements in a list so they can easily be removed when the list grows too long. Note that I didn't strictly monitor this list such to delete the tweet as soon as it leaves the screen: I think that's overkill here as I really can't foresee one, ten or one hundred tweets using much memory at all. Instead, there's just a threshold (which should be set generously) after which a tweet will be deleted each time a new one is displayed.

   - Tweets are added and removed from this list in a [first-in-first-out (FIFO) manner](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FIFO_(computing_and_electronics)) (by using `Array.push` to add to the end, and `Array.shift` to remove from the beginning), as opposed to a [last-in-first-out (LIFO) manner](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack_(abstract_data_type)) (by using `Array.push` to add to the end, and `Array.pop` to remove from the end). This is important to achieving the desired effect.
3. Apply a class to each new tweet so they can display their alternating backgrounds. It was necessary to keep a counter here such to know whether the new tweet is odd or even.

   - Note that CSS can generally be used for this kind of thing. However, because tweets will eventually be deleted *from the beginning of the list*, you'd experience all of the tweets alternating backgrounds each time a tweet is deleted.
   - You could work around this is if you really wanted to, for instance by deleting two tweets at a time instead of only one (and thus preserving their odd and even states).
4. A CSS "trick" using `position`, `bottom: 0`, `min-height: 100%` and `overflow: hidden` which forced the tweet box to take the full container height initially, and continue to grow *upwards* (meaning the newest tweet will remain visible at the bottom). The `overflow: hidden` will prevent all that had grown upwards from being visible to the user. The combined effect is what I imagined you meant when you described your "autoscrolling".

   - The example is simplified in that it's being applied to a single element with `position: fixed`. In reality, I suspect that you'd have the tweet box contained in a different element. You can use the other kinds of `position`s to achieve the same result there. If you need help with that, shoot me a comment.

Here's the example:

```js
// Hold onto our tweet box so we can manipulate it.
var tweetBox = document.getElementById("tweetBox");

// Maintain a list (or `Array`) of displayed tweets,
// which we'll use again when it's time to delete them.
var displayedTweets = [];

// Need to decide when to start deleting tweets.
// Be generous: tweets won't consume much memory.
// We certainly don't want them disappearing prematurely.
var deleteTweetsAfter = 100;

// We'll keep track of a tweet number
// so we can apply alternating styles to the tweets
// (and not have them change when tweets are deleted).
var tweetNumber = 0;

// Here's our function to display a tweet.
// You should call this function
// when your socket receives a new tweet.
function displayNewTweet(text) {
  // We'll create a new element to display our tweet in.
  var newTweetDiv = document.createElement("div");

  // Specify a different class
  // depending on whether `tweetNumber` is odd or even.
  tweetNumber += 1;
  newTweetDiv.className = tweetNumber % 2 == 0 ? 'even' : 'odd';

  // You can put whatever HTML you like in this `div`, like so:
  newTweetDiv.innerHTML += "<p>" + text + "</p>";

  // Add this new element to the end of the tweet box.
  tweetBox.appendChild(newTweetDiv);

  // Also add it to the _end_ of our array.
  // This is important for when we start deleting tweets,
  // which you'll see below.
  displayedTweets.push(newTweetDiv);

  // Check if we've exceeded our tweet limit.
  if (displayedTweets.length > deleteTweetsAfter) {
    // Pop the _first_ tweet out of our array..
    var tweetToDelete = displayedTweets.shift();

    // and remove it from our tweet box.
    tweetBox.removeChild(tweetToDelete);

    // You can use console logging to know it actually worked.
    // console.log(tweetBox, tweetToDelete);
  }
}

// I've added a button to test this.
// This is how it'd be hooked up the new tweet function:
var testTweeter = document.getElementById("testTweeter");
testTweeter.onclick = function() {
  var tweetText = "Awesome tweet, with randomness: ";
  tweetText += Math.random().toString();

  displayNewTweet(tweetText);
};

// You'd use your sockets to call this function:
// socket.on('newTweet', displayNewTweet);
```

```css
#left {
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 200px;
  /* `min-height` + `bottom: 0;` is the "autoscroll" magic -
     the element will keep growing _upwards_
     but it can't be seen so nobody would notice. */
  min-height: 100%;
  overflow: none;
  background: grey;
}
#tweetBox > div.odd {
  background: cyan;
}
#tweetBox > div.even {
  background: yellow;
}
#right {
  margin-left: 200px;
}
```

```html
<div id="left">
  <div id="tweetBox">
  </div>
</div>

<div id="right">
  <button id="testTweeter">Add test tweet</button>
</div>
```

You can run the above code snippet (in a desktop browser) to see what it looks like, right here. To make the example work I added a button which will generate fake tweets.

Comment: Thanks! Works exactly as intended, I appreciate it.